# Voltage doubler circuit for heater

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a ceramic heater, which needs to work with 24V but I only have a 12V power supply. Now, I am trying to design voltage doubler.

[image]

Does the above circuit is suitable to power the ceramic heater (40W @ 24V)?

Comment: Those diodes are only signal diodes, not power diodes

Comment: What is the power (or current) rating of the ceramic heater?

Comment: Something like this would do the job - http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Auto-Boost-Buck-Converter-CC-CV-5-30V-To-1-30V-8A-12V-24V-Voltage-Regulator-100W-/171925218848?hash=item28078aa620

Comment: No. Charge pumps are feasible for several miliamperes at best. The simplest solution for this case is boost converter.

Comment: Although it's pretty obvious from the circuit the IC is a 555, you haven't labeled it as such.or mentioned it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the above circuit is suitable to power the ceramic heater (40W @
>   24V)?

Certainly not. 1N4148 diodes at the output will fry in an instant. Also the power dissipation in the transistors will be about 3 or 4 watts so you ought to consider a heatsink. I don't know why you have back-to-back 1N4148 diodes feeding the transistors - these will reduce the drive to the push-pull pair resulting in approximately a further couple of watts in the transistors being generated as heat.